# How can I sort words of Unicode sequence in php?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, utf-8, internationalization

Example:

'lemon orange banana apple' ---> 'elmno aegnor aaabnn aelpp' 
'лимон апельсин банан яблоко' ---> 'илмно аеилнпсь аабнн бклооя' 
'αβγαβγ αβγαβγαβγ' ---> 'ααββγγ αααβββγγγ'

Comment: Sorting in the Unicode world is complex, as several codepoints may make on character, such as surrogate pairs, normalisation will affect the sequence and composition of characters, before you get to which collation you are going to use.  Then of course you need to find a working definition for a word. Not all languages have word separators. I'm sorry, but you will need a huge amount of knowledge to decide what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

function array_sorting($string) {

```
// Split string sequence into array elements
$string = explode(" ", $string);
//print_r($string);

foreach($string as $str) {

    // Converting words into array elements
    $results = array();
    preg_match_all('/./u', $str, $results);

    foreach ( $results as $array ) {

        // Sorting array elements
        sort($array);

        // Concat elements back to words
        foreach($array as $val){
            echo $val;
        }
    }
    // Concat words back to sequence
    echo " ";
}
```

}

array_sorting('αβγαβγ αβγαβγαβγ');

Comment: I did it by myself ;-)